# get host but while the host application is closed

Tags: c#

the following code get the host application ,in this case for CorelDraw application and it run correctly in case of corelDraw in runing and the exe runs by corelDraw:

```
  Corel.Interop.CorelDRAW.Application appDRAW =
                                    new  Corel.Interop.CorelDRAW.Application();
  app = (Application)this.Host;
```

but for some complicated reason ,I need to make this code run even without corel is running but I am not going to use the app instance unless the corel is running so any way to get the host application by name or something like that or just to point to the exe of the host application even before it is running

maybe something like

```
app = (Application) getHostByExe("c:\corelPath\corel.exe");
```

and advice,

Comment: But the whole point of the interop call is you don't have to know where the host is and it's filename, and what do you mean make this code work without corel running?

Comment: I mean I want the code to be accepted and complied ,and later in the run time I will be sure that corel is running so code will not raise errors,

Comment: Interop isn't going to stop it compiling. Are you saying you want a way of checking that Corel will run, without simply making a call on it and see if it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved for me

```
Dim obj As Object
Dim app As c.Application

obj = GetObject("", "CorelDRAW.Application")
app = CType(obj, c.Application)
```